# CSS inheritance issue

Tags: css, inheritance

I have a old css line taking precedence over my new `<img>` ID CSS how can I over-ride this?

I'm looking to change the width of an image within greybar, and cannot change the image width with a new ID.

Here's my code:

```
#greybar img {
    width: 75px;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;  
}    

#rpmimage { 
    width: 125px;
}
```

Comment: show the html as well. css without the html it's applying to is rather useless.

Comment: Agree with Marc! but you can do this: `width: 75px !important;` on #greybar img

Answer (score 3):

You need to look up CSS Specificity. In short, different selectors get a different score.

An ID is worth 100, a Class is worth 10, and a tag selector is worth 1.

That means that `#greybar img` is worth 101, whereas `#rpmimage` is worth 100. Hence, the first one 'wins'.

Many people recommend not using IDs for CSS, and not to over-qualify selectors where needed to help.

In you case, try `#rpmimage img` instead, or rethink what you are doing with this new knowledge!

There are a variety of 'bad things' to do, including using inline styles (like you'll remember you did that next time you have a problem!), or using `!important`. Thing with `!important` is that it takes priority over everything which means next time you have this issue you have nowhere to go.

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/ is a great article that has some good practice in it, and is worth reading for everyone really!

For a nice tool to help understand more complex selectors, try http://specificity.keegan.st/ - this lets you test things like `#id:after p > img` to see what specificity they have.

Answer (score -2):

I think you should be able to do an in-line style, at least as a quick and dirty trick.

For example:

```
<img style="width:75px;" ... >
```

Comment: Please no, inline styling doesn't _fix_ the problem, it just hides it